# Date Picker looks squashed as input of a Text Field

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uidatepicker, ios14

I have a `UITextField` that is using `UIDatePicker` as an input. I set the Date Picker's style to be `.inline`, but the result is not what I expected

[image]

As you can see, the hour selector in the Date Picker looks squashed.

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: view.center,
                                                  size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 30)))
        textField.text = "TEST"
        textField.inputView = datePicker

        self.view.addSubview(textField)
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Why not just use the `.compact` style and remove the text field altogether?

Comment: Or just use wheel style.

Comment: Having the same issue and I'm on iOS 14 GM. If this is a bug, it's worrying that it's not fixed at this point...

Comment: @Insleep i just changed to .compact. Maybe this is not how is intended to be used. I would expect more people to stumble on the same thing.

Comment: Use this link ;-https://stackoverflow.com/a/64160213/7300477

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
   datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
```

Comment: But how to support older versions?

Comment: That's the big question. The solution above won't compile for Xcode below 11.6.

Comment: @Shubh That is what the `#available` is for.